# macro in function declaration

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm looking at the v4l header files and I found function definitions with the following structure.

```
#define SOME_VAR

SOME_VAR int somefunc(int i,....);
```

What is the purpose of using the #define directive in such a way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Purposes of this vary but they're generally centered around specialized tool usage; markers for an IDE to find certain things, markers for custom preprocessing / static analyzing tools, or placeholders for attributes that may be applied in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a calling convention or a import/export tag. For example Visual Studio you build a DLL and have some functions to export, you can reuse your header file. For compiling the export you use

```
#define SOME_VAR __declspec(dllexport)
```

on the import site you write

```
#define SOME_VAR __declspec(dllimport)
```

using only one include in both situations reduce the possible errors during updating and bug fixing of the code.

In the case you mentioned above it seems to be for future use as some platforms have other calling conventions (e.g. the pascal calling convention) than others.

Visual Studio uses a similar stub, the macro WINAPI, which is also empty.